# Which approach would lead to an API that is easier to use?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm writing a JavaScript API and for a particular case, I'm wondering which approach is the sexiest. Let's take an example: writing a `VideoPlayer`, I add a `getCurrentTime` method which gives the elapsed time since the start.

1. The first approach simply declares `getCurrentTime` as follows:

   ```
   getCurrentTime():number
   ```

   where `number` is the **native number** type. This approach includes a `CURRENT_TIME_CHANGED` event so that API users can add callbacks to be aware of time changes. Listening to this event would look like the following:

   ```
   myVideoPlayer.addEventListener(CURRENT_TIME_CHANGED, function(evt){
       console.log ("current time = "+evt.getDispatcher().getCurrentTime());
   });
   ```
2. The second approach declares `getCurrentTime` differently:

   ```
   getCurrentTime():CustomNumber
   ```

   where `CustomNumber` is a **custom number** object, not the native one. This custom object dispatches a `VALUE_CHANGED` event when its value changes, so there is no need for the `CURRENT_TIME_CHANGED` event! Just listen to the returned object for value changes! Listening to this event would look like the following:

   ```
   myVideoPlayer.getCurrentTime().addEventListener(VALUE_CHANGED, function(evt){
       console.log ("current time = "+evt.getDispatcher().valueOf());
   });
   ```

   Note that `CustomNumber` has a `valueOf` method which returns a native number that lets the returned `CustomNumber` object being used as a number, so:

   ```
   var result = myVideoPlayer.getCurrentTime()+5;
   ```

   will work!

So in the first approach, we listen to an object for a change in its property's value. In the second one we directly listen to the property for a change on its value. There are multiple pros and cons for each approach, I just want to know which one the developers would prefer to use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the first approach. When people use a method like `getCurrentTime()` and store the returned value, they expect that that value will remain the time at the moment they called the method. Having that value suddenly change is going to be a source of great confusion:

```
prevTime = myVideoPlayer.getCurrentTime();
//...at some later point
timeElapsed = myVideoPlayer.getCurrentTime() - prevTime;
```

Now `timeElapsed` is `0`, which is wrong. The correct code for that API would be:

```
prevTime = myVideoPlayer.getCurrentTime().valueOf();
//...at some later point
timeElapsed = myVideoPlayer.getCurrentTime() - prevTime;
```

But this way is very uncommon, and most people will instinctively use the first method and get confusing bugs.

Comment: Thank you! I'm agree with you, that is what i anticipate but i wasn't able to find an exemple that show why it is better. I cannot vote yet since my reputation here is not enough... Whatever, thank you!